# ASP.NET full website examples with code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

One of the most obnoxious things about developing a website from scratch is dealing with all incidental menuing, layout and all of that.

I am looking for the following: Open source C# ASP.NET website examples of more or less complete but rudimentary websites that include navigation and (hopefully) rudimentary DB access.

I am NOT looking for a full blown CMS like DNN, or Umbraco.

I am looking for a downloadable project that contains navigation, layout, and DB access with either no internal content or easily stripped content.

Note: I am NOT new to ASP.NET. I just am looking for a fast way to get through the initial road humps of a VS project without always starting with only a blank page.

Comment: maybe not so releveant but : if you have a starter template for new projects ( login, error pages etc and you dont want to create everything from scracth you can use http://haacked.com/archive/2011/06/06/creating-a-custom-asp-net-mvc-project-template.aspx ) or you use your create your  custom nuget package and serve it on local nuget server .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a bunch of starter kits available on the asp.net community site:  http://www.asp.net/aspnet/samples

There is also http://www.nerddinner.com (source code at http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) if you're interested in ASP.NET MVC.

**EDIT:**

If you're just looking for easy to setup login functionality, why not use [ASP.NET Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx)?

The [Menu control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecs0x9w5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is also fairly easy to configure, especially with [sitemap files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy2ykkab.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

In this MSDN tutorial, they actually explain ASP.NET well and also give a link to download the tutorial. I am not sure if it has the DB access..but it is worthwhile to look at it I guess. Here is the [tutorial #3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581781.aspx). On the top of the page, you can download all the files used in the tutorial